# Get html of div in codebehind ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I want to get rendered html for a div control in codebehind of ASP.NET WebForms page which uses a master page. The div contains ASP.NET controls along with some paragraphs.

**Following is the illustrative code in aspx design file.**

```
<div id="FormContainer" runat="server">
<p>This is sample paragraph</p>

<asp:TextBox ID="PhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPN" ontrolToValidate="PhoneNumberTextBox" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter phone number." Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</div>
```

I tried to use following code to get rendered html string but it failed with an error:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
FormContainer.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(stringBuilder)));
var htmlString = sb.ToString();
```

**Error message**:

**Control `MainContent_PhoneNumberTextBox` of type `TextBox` must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.**

---

How can I get contents of `FormContainer` div in codebehind?

Is there any better way to do this?

Please help.

Comment: I have marked it as duplicate even if it's not so obvious that it is one. But the reason for the error is the same. You have to overrride `VerifyRenderingInServerForm`.

Comment: I am trying to find solution for this, if it is duplicate please help me be providing any link for original question. I have seen similar questions with error message similar I have posted in this question but the context is different here.

Comment: I have already closed it as duplicate. Just look at the top of your question, there is the link

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter, I was banging my head from last hour to solve this error. The links does looks helpful and should help me solve this error. Sorry for last comment, I didn't checked link at top of page.